# Google app engine JPA ancestor queries

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

i was wondering if is there any cost/performance difference in using ancestor queries.

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT FROM File f WHERE f.parentID = :parentID AND f.someOtherNumber > :xx");
q.setParameter("parentID", KeyFactory.createKey("User", 2343334443334L));
q.setParameter("xx",233);

//File class with ancestors
@Entity
class File{
    @Id
    @....
    public Key ID;

    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.parent-pk", value ="true")
public Key parentID;
};
```

OR

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT FROM File f WHERE f.parentID = :parentID AND f.someOtherNumber > :xx");
q.setParameter("parentID", 2343334443334L);
q.setParameter("xx",233);

//File class without ancestors
@Entity
class File{
    @Id
    @....
    public Key ID;

public long parentID;
};
```

I was testing some stuff and if i use ancestor query my index doesn't include parentID(it says with ancestors) the non ancestor version it does.
Is there a difference in index/datastore read/write cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writing costs might be slightly lower (one fewer indexed property), but the storage costs might be slightly higher (a key for each child entity includes all of its ancestors).

In either case, the differences are insignificant unless you have a billion records. You will face more serious performance/cost differences depending on your data access patterns (i.e. how you access the data most of the time).